# Is there a Golang Websocket library that would let me modify the initial request / let me pick the http.Client?

Tags: http, go, websocket, kerberos, gorilla

I want to connect to a websocket server, but the endpoint is Kerberos authenticated. I have a library that is able to Kerberos authenticate requests, and I also have an http.Client wrapper that authenticates all requests sent through it to whatever endpoint.

Neither of my tools seem to be of any use with gorilla/websocket. I've tried a few things, including sending an authenticated GET request, then passing the response headers into websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(), but that doesn't work since the actual handshake request itself isn't authenticated.

Hence, I am perplexed. Does anyone have ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: What specifically does not work with the Gorilla package. With the Gorilla package, the application can create the underlying network connection, set handshake request headers and access handshake response headers.

Comment: Hi Cerise, Dial() passes the http.Header as the header for the initial upgrade request, right? My issue is that the websocket server is Kerberos-authenticated. I need to have the upgrade request itself authenticated.

Comment: Using Gorilla I think you can add to the headers that you pass to websocket.Upgrade().

Comment: @pure_Redwood  You have control over the network connection and th headers.  What else do you  need for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Here is what I do:

1. I send a Kerberos-authenticated GET request to any authenticated endpoint on the server.
2. I then authenticate the Response and grab the Cookie.
3. I create a Kerberos-authenticated GET request to the websocket endpoint and add the Cookie to its header.
4. Then I dial via gorilla/websocket

The issue was the treatment of the cookie. Leaving the answer here in case people run into similar troubles with Kerberos or other auth services.